# Linking VBA to HTML code

Tags: html, vba

I am  a beginner in VBA and i have a question regarding sending the Enter key or another way to access that element in HTML.

Please note that there is no search button an i can't use click(on the search button).
I've tried "Sendkeys "{Enter}", True " but it doesn't work

The Html line is like

```
   <input id="tiSearch" style="width:150px; margin: 5px 10px 0 5px" name="s" type="text" value="Search (Ctrl+S)..." onkeypress="checkEnter(event)">
```

Thank you ,
Serban

Comment: Please show your code (revise your question to include the code you are currently trying to use), and also include a link to the URL (if it is publicly available).

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.SendKeys "~", True
```

Had the same problem and thought it would be `{Enter}` as well.